# Pre-C++14 template metaprogramming and conditional operator

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, conditional-operator

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other):

> Such conditional operator was commonly used in C++11 constexpr
>   programming prior to C++14.
>
> ```
> std::string str = 2+2==4 ? "ok" : throw std::logic_error("2+2 != 4");
> ```

What does cppreference refer to? What was the pre-C++14 idiom and why in C++14 that technique is no longer relevant?

Comment: Before C++14 a `constexpr` function was only allowed to have one single statement which is `return`, no loops, no branches, etc.  That is why people used the ternary operator in the return statement to circumvent this restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you could not have more than one statement, basically, in a `constexpr` function.  In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you can.

```
constexpr bool str(int x){
  return  2+2==x ? true : throw std::logic_error("2+2 != x");
}
```

vs [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14):

```
constexpr bool str(int x){
  if (2+2==x)
    return true;
  else
     throw std::logic_error("2+2 != x");
}
```